# How to clean up setInterval in useEffect using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a loading component that will add a period to a div periodically, every 1000ms using setInterval in React. I am trying to cleanup setInterval using the method described in the docs.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const Loading = () => {
    const [loadingStatus, setLoadingStatus] = useState('.')
    const [loop, setLoop] = useState()
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoop(setInterval(() => {
            console.log("loading")
            setLoadingStatus(loadingStatus + ".")
        }, 1000))

        return function cleanup() {
            console.log('cleaning up')
            clearInterval(loop)
        }
    }, [])
    return (<p>
        {`Loading ${loadingStatus}`}
    </p>)
}
export default Loading
```

However , the loadingStatus variable only updates once and the setInterval loop doesnt get cleared even after the component stops mounting. Do I have to make this using a class component?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Dependencies are our hint for React of when the effect should run, even though we set an interval and providing no dependencies `[]`, React wont know we want to run it more then once because nothing really changes in our empty dependencies `[]`.

To get the desired result we need to think when we want to run the effect ?

We want to run it when `loadingStatus` changes, so we need to add `loadingStatus` as our dependency because we want to run the effect every time `loadingStatus` changes.

We have 2 options

Add `loadingStatus` as our dependency.

```
const Loading = () => {
  const [loadingStatus, setLoadingStatus] = useState(".");
  const [loop, setLoop] = useState();

  useEffect(
    () => {
      setLoop(
        setInterval(() => {
          console.log("loading");
          setLoadingStatus(loadingStatus + ".");
        }, 1000)
      );

      return function cleanup() {
        console.log("cleaning up");
        clearInterval(loop);
      };
    },
    [loadingStatus]
  );

  return <p>{`Loading ${loadingStatus}`}</p>;
};
```

Make our effect not aware that we use `loadingStatus`

```
const Loading = () => {
  const [loadingStatus, setLoadingStatus] = useState(".");

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setLoadingStatus(ls => ls + ".");
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

  return <p>{`Loading ${loadingStatus}`}</p>;
};
```

Read more here => [a-complete-guide-to-useeffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

Comment: Why doesn't your useEffect take `loop` as a dependency even though it uses it during the cleanup. Of course adding it to the dependencies will make it refire continuously