# react.js slowly degrading performance with rerenders on setIntervals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

i'm building a rock paper scissors war simulator just to practice and encountered a performance issue. I got a homescreen where the user can setup the amount of units of each team and the speed each unit will move (not implemented yet)

when click start, we navigate to the war page where each team have it's units spawned on a quadrant. There are only 3 classes. First I tried with setInterval on each unit constructor, but that would make several intervals being listened. Then I have placed only 1 interval that iterates through all units, moving them.

The problem is that the application slowly degrades it's performance. If my interval is of 100 milliseconds, all units moves a little but very fast, and will slowing over time until after around 45 seconds they stop moving at all. This is the code:

war class

```
export class War {
    teams: Team[] = []
    render: () => void

    constructor(data: WarOptions) {
        this.render = data.render

        this.teams.push(new Team({ image: rock, sector_x: 1, sector_y: 1, ...data }))
        this.teams.push(new Team({ image: paper, sector_x: 2, sector_y: 1, ...data }))
        this.teams.push(new Team({ image: scissors, sector_x: 1, sector_y: 2, ...data }))

        setInterval(() => {
            this.teams.forEach((team) => {
                team.units.forEach((unit) => unit.move())
            })
            this.render()
        }, 100)
    }
}
```

team class (rock, paper or scissors)

```
export class Team {
    units: Unit[] = []
    image: string

    constructor(data: TeamOptions) {
        this.image = data.image

        for (let index = 1; index <= data.units; index++) {
            const unit = new Unit(data)
            this.units.push(unit)
        }
    }
}
```

unit class

```
export class Unit {
    id: string
    x: number
    y: number
    image: string

    width = 30
    height = 30

    render: () => void

    constructor(data: UnitOptions) {
        this.id = uid()
        const { x, y } = this.generatePos(data.sector_x, data.sector_y, data.quadrant_size)
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.image = data.image
        this.render = data.render
    }

    generatePos(sector_x: number, sector_y: number, quadrant_size: number) {
        const max_x = quadrant_size * sector_x
        const min_x = max_x - quadrant_size
        const max_y = quadrant_size * sector_y
        const min_y = max_y - quadrant_size

        let x = random.int(min_x, max_x)
        let y = random.int(min_y, max_y)

        if (x + this.width > max_x) {
            x = this.generatePos(sector_x, sector_y, quadrant_size).x
        }

        if (y + this.height > max_y) {
            y = this.generatePos(sector_x, sector_y, quadrant_size).y
        }

        return { x, y }
    }

    private generateX() {
        return random.int(-1, 1)
    }

    private generateY() {
        return random.int(-1, 1)
    }

    move() {
        let x = this.generateX()
        let y = this.generateY()

        if (this.x + x < 0 || this.x + x > 1080) {
            x = this.generateX()
        }

        if (this.y + y < 0 || this.y + y > 1080) {
            y = this.generateX()
        }

        this.x += x
        this.y += y
    }
}
```

war react page

```
export const GamePage: React.FC<GamePageProps> = ({}) => {
    const { settings } = useContext(SettingsContext)
    const [render, setRender] = useState({})

    const war_options: WarOptions = {
        units: settings.units,
        quadrant_size: Math.floor(window.innerHeight / 2),
        render: () => setRender({}),
    }

    const [war, setWar] = useState(new War(war_options))

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(war)
    }, [])

    return <Box sx={{ position: "relative" }}>{war.teams.map((team) => team.units.map((unit) => <Troop key={unit.id} unit={unit} />))}</Box>
```

each unit react component

```
export const Troop: React.FC<TroopProps> = ({ unit }) => {
    return <CardMedia sx={{ position: "absolute", left: unit.x, top: unit.y, width: unit.width, height: unit.height }} image={unit.image}></CardMedia>
}
```

for all react layout components i'm using Mui's Box and CardMedia. Any ideas on how can I get it working without that degenerative slow? Thanks!!

update:
It seems this problem have nothing to do with the fact it's classes. I have implemented the classes on a server (localhost) and emitting the updates via socketio. My client listens to this update event and updates the teams state accordingly. Same thing is happening. Now there is no setInterval and react is rerendering normally when teams state mutates, which is happening every 100ms through socketio, but again starts pretty normal and slowly degrades it's performance after a couple minutes it's completely stoped.

Comment: Try clearing your intervals to avoid accumulating a bunch of them doing the same thing. Take a look at this answer for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/55764160/10926702

Comment: but there is only 1 interval since it's on the War constructor and it's only being instantiated once.

I have already tried to move the setInterval to an useEffect block and clearing it on the cleaunp function, nothing changed :(